# Xampp controller Panel become error

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp, control-panel

I dont know why. suddenly, after i restart my laptop and open my XAMPP controller panel. it become error

[here's the controllor panel image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnjJ0.png)

i can't start apache and mysql. beside that, the text below become tiny. and it display error message

```
11:44:32 AM  [main]     Initializing Control Panel
11:44:32 AM  [main]     Windows Version: Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 64-bit
11:44:32 AM  [main]     XAMPP Version: 7.1.9
11:44:32 AM  [main]     Control Panel Version: 3.2.2  [ Compiled: Nov 12th 2015 ]
11:44:32 AM  [main]     You are not running with administrator rights! This will work for
11:44:32 AM  [main]     most application stuff but whenever you do something with services
11:44:32 AM  [main]     there will be a security dialogue or things will break! So think 
11:44:32 AM  [main]     about running this application with administrator rights!
11:44:32 AM  [main]     XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\"
11:44:32 AM  [main]     Checking for prerequisites
11:44:32 AM  [main]     Initializing Modules
11:44:32 AM  [main]     The  module is disabled
11:44:32 AM  [main]     The  module is disabled
11:44:32 AM  [main]     The  module is disabled
11:44:32 AM  [main]     The  module is disabled
11:44:32 AM  [main]     The  module is disabled
11:44:32 AM  [main]     Starting Check-Timer
11:44:32 AM  [main]     Control Panel Ready
```

what should i do.

Comment: Try running XAMPP with administrator privilages.

Comment: still same. nothing change

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue out of nowhere. The only thing that 100% fixed it was do delete the `xampp-control.ini` file in the `xampp/` directory.

Comment: In the latest version of xampp (PHP 7.4.x), there's a mixed-permissions issue with that file (see file properties), which for some reason the xampp control panel uses for all kinds of counter-intuitive stuff